# Adding a CNAME to an AWS EC2 Public Domain Name

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

I have a test application running at

```
http://ec2-34-215-196-193.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
```

(This is a Test application, it wont be live for long. When I try to add a CNAME to this, like the screenshot below

[image: img]

- `.` is added by the DNS system.
- However, my app seems to be accessible only via `us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` or `us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.`
- I can make it to resolve it either one of them.

But adding anything, does not seem to resolve with a CNAME.  It gives `503 Service Unavailable`.

- I am using AWS EC2 to host the app with a HAProxy Load Balancer.
- Using Google Domains for DNS Name.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: The question is not clear fully though, is your expectation to point readthedocs.io -> HA proxy -> EC2 instance? to serve content from EC2 via a the proxy. First of all why are you using HA proxy? Then do you have LoadBalancers setup?

Comment: This is not a DNS issue, your CNAME is fine. Apparently your webserver/app will respond properly only if `Host` header contains server's hostname

Comment: @DusanBajic - how did you figure this out?

Comment: Well first, `503` is a response, so you reached *something* (you did not get `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` or timeout). Next, you can easily see (or manually resolve) your instance's public IP address from hostname; Then I just tried that IP address directly in browser address bar and got also `503`, so it was safe to assume that I reached the same server you connected to with your `CNAME`. And if the IP address is the same one, the only thing that differs between two requests is the `Host` header.

Answer (score 1):

All dns entries have a dot in the end like subdomain.domain.com. 
It's not suggested to create CNAMEs to your ec2 instance because that IP may vary in time and it's not reassignable, that's what elastic ip's are made for, just create an elastic IP, assign it to your ec2 instance and assign it as an A record on your DNS provider.

[Amazon AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html)

Answer (score 0):

First create elastic IP and assign to your instance. Then create A record and point IP. Your site should work normal.